Live Persona Card Custom Properties
Can I change the live persona card properties i.e., Custom Name, department etc. Currently it always showing against mail given in user object. I also use static display name in user object but it's always showing data against mail. The is given below that I am using. Thanks in advance.
      <LivePersonaCard
        user={{
          displayName: "",
          email: props.context.pageContext.user.email,
        }}

        serviceScope={props.context.serviceScope}
        personaProps={{
          //imageUrl: require('../assets/welcome-dark.png'),
          className: "personaStyle",
          //secondaryText: "Test Consultant",
          //isOutOfOffice: false,
          //size: PersonaSize.size48,
          coinSize: 32,
          //presence: PersonaPresence.none
        }}
      />

